# Why cast an int to byte in BufferedOutputStream write method that takes an int argument?

Tags: java, casting, outputstream

In "Introduction to Java Programming," 9th ed, by Y. Daniel Liang, in chapter 19 about binary IO is written a code example where the `write()` method casts an int to a byte. Why?

For example:

```
    /*
     *  Read and write bytes.
     */
    int intByte = 0;

    int numberOfBytesCopied = 0;

    while( (intByte = bufferedInputStream.read()) != -1){

        bufferedOutputStream.write((byte)intByte);

        numberOfBytesCopied ++;
    }
```

[Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(int)) indicates three overloaded write methods: one takes a byte array, the other takes a byte array (allowing for start and end points to be designated), the other takes an int.

Why does the text cast `intByte` above to a byte? And by making that cast I don't see a `write` method that takes a single byte? Since the program runs without error, is the int-cast-to-a-byte being recast to an int by JVM? Or is the lonely byte being converted by the JVM to an array with a single element to satisfy the `write` parameter? Or?

I coded the example and ran it with the cast and without the cast, both run without incident. So I'm tempted to do away with the cast but figure there's a reason for it I don't understand.

Comment: What happens if the stream you copy contains values >127?

Comment: The doc you point to answers the question I think: `he byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of the argument b. The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored.`

Comment: Ah. So even though the argument to `write` is an int, which is 4 bytes, only the lowest byte of that int is written. So the cast is kind of superfluous because only the lowest 8 bits are considered anyway. So "in a way" the `write(int)` method is really looking for an 8-bit argument, doesn't really care if its an int or a byte.

Comment: @rossstudtman I'm still not 100% convinced this code works correctly when used with bytes >127. Shouldn't `(int)((byte)255)` evaluate to -1 instead of 255?

Comment: @biziclop I don't quite understand; the file I'm reading from is a text file (technically maybe a reader would be more accurate with that?) - and I'm a touch fuzzy, I'll admit, on characters being read as bytes. With my limited understanding UTF-8 can write up to 3 bytes but ASCII uses a single byte (cringe)? If I had written a crazy character that used all 3 bytes then reading it via an InputStream's `read` would require 3 OutputStream `writes` to write the full character?

Comment: @biziclop thats right, but the lowest 8 bits of -1 are still 0xff

Comment: @Henry Ah, of course. So it works but only by coincidence. Well, not quite but you know what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By casting the `intByte` to a `byte`, the value is narrowed from 32-bit to 8-bit. The `write()` method can accept a byte even though its signature asks for an int -- this is called widening (no cast required). That part is inconsequential. But the cast from `int` to `byte` is important since it could dramatically affect the value of the variable by trimming off the leading 24 bits. Try this, for example, and see what happens:

`int i = 13465878;
byte b = (byte)i;
System.out.println("i as a byte is " + b);`

Comment: "i is a byte is 22" - my ignorance is precluding me from understanding exactly why 22.

Comment: Thanks for the widening aspect. How would a file know I was reading ints from the bytes? Or was that more of a caution not to willy-nilly convert ints to bytes and think all will go well? The conversion loses nothing in the code example because the `read` method is only grabbing a single byte, then converting that to an int, so lopping off the upper 3 bytes from that int won't do anything, with this usage?

Comment: "A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T." Explained here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3

Comment: Got it, Richard :) the lowest order of bits of the number 13465878 is 00010110 ...which is 22. Good, good, up to speed(ish). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Technically there is no reason for the cast. Maybe the author thought the program is clearer if the cast is included.

Comment: Thank you, Henry, for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

The cast doesn't matter here since fortunately in the BufferedOutputStream.write() method
cast will happen.

```
public synchronized void write(int b) throws IOException {
    if (count >= buf.length) {
        flushBuffer();
    }
    buf[count++] = (byte)b;
}
```

as documentation says the method only writes 8 first bit and the rest will be ignored.
this is the effect of casting int type to byte.

I think the author put the cast to clarify what is going to write into output! this way the unaware developers don't need to consult JavaDoc to see what will be written to output!

It is always good practice to clarify your code as much as possible.

P.S: code runs as folows
intByte will cast to byte then 
because of effect of widening write(int) method will be called
and the rest...